Writing permissions on mounted NAS in my linux machine
I have a NAS in my home with all my shared files. I want to mount this storage in my linux terminal and I have accomplished that by adding:
//192.168.0.145/TARDIS_Share /mnt/nas cifs username=MY_USERNAME,password=MY_PASSWORD,uid=3000,gid=3002,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775 0 0

inside /etc/fstab
and then running on bash
mount -a

However, when I try to run any command that generates a file it returns a writing permission error.
Im running Ubuntu:
No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Release: 22.04 Codename: jammy
I've tested saving a simple text file with VIM and I can only do it by running vim as sudo.
How can I change writing permissions so as I can create files without using su commands?

Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Im running Ubuntu, check it out:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
